# Examples of cucumber features with chargify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, chargify

Does anyone have examples of cucumber features that uses the chargify APIs (particularly with the chargify_api_ares gem)?  I want to write features that create customers and also utilize a factory of customers, but I can't think of a way to clean up the chargify test account whenever cucumber features complete their run.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to avoid hitting the API at all, by faking the responses with [Fakeweb](https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb)

This will speed up your tests :) And decoupling them from external services is a Good Thing in general - saves bandwidth, ensures your tests will run if the service is down, etc